# Spring: DispatcherServlet and static content

Tags: spring-mvc, mapping

In my Spring web-app i have mapped `/app/*` to dispatcher servlet. What is the **best approach** in that scenerio to separate a static content like `images`, `.js`, `.css` from dispatcher ?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For example, when i open url: `http://server/context/app/users` and on users.jsp have `<img src="images/test.png"/>` i get no image because `http://server/conext/app/users/images/test.png` is not a right url.

Now i use absolute path like: `<img src="/context/images/test.png"/>` but it complicates JSP code a little and searching something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<mvc:resources>` to tell the `DispatcherServlet` that certain paths should be handles as static resources.

See [section 15.12.4 of the Spring 3.0.x manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) for how to configure it.

Comment: yes, this is right but what happen if resources and controller path are same?

Comment: the answer is in xml style, how about code based configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I serve static content using this configuration which will default if there is no handler mapping found for a URL and just serves the URL.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```