# spring mvc javascript / css locations

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to access static resources with Spring MVC like images, JavaScript and CSS. After some research I found that I can access those by putting following entries in `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But by this I am not able to access resources under `WEB-INF/` folder. I want all my resources to be under `WEB-INF/` folder only to control access. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this in application-servlet.xml:

```
     <!-- static resource mapping for style sheets, etc. -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**"  location="/WEB-INF/skins/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/WEB-INF/scripts/" />
```

And on the page you could have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/scripts/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${context}/styles/css/superfish.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell spring where the static resources are

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />`

This would make all files that are under WEB-INF/ and all files that are in jars in the META-INF/web-resources accessible at

> http://example.org/app/resources/

See also
[Spring: DispatcherServlet and static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976266/spring-dispatcherservlet-and-static-content)

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources