# Spring MVC: UI-Testing with Test WebApplicationContext and embedded Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, selenium-webdriver, embedded-jetty

**tldr;** How do I deploy from WebApplicationContext in embedded jetty for a simple automatic test case?

#### What I have:

A spring application (not spring boot) that uses annotation configuration (no web.xml) and is - for production - build (with gradle) to an ear and deployed on wildfly.

#### What I ultimately want to do:

Have self-contained (in the applications test package) ui-tests, that can easily be executed (without building and deploying) like any of the other unit or integration tests.

#### What I have done so far:

- The easy part: Setup the actual tests with Selenium WebDriver
- The hard part: Start an embedded Jetty with a test WebApplicationContext

My code for the embedded Jetty (yes, I will do some refactoring when I get it running):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner;
import org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class JettyServerFactory {

    private Server server = null;

    public Server start(WebApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        if (server == null) {
            this.server = new Server(9090);
            setupServer(context);

            server.start();
            //server.join();
        }
        return server;
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        if (server != null) {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    private void setupServer(WebApplicationContext context) throws Exception {

        final ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();

        // Since this is a ServletContextHandler we must manually configure JSP support.
        enableEmbeddedJspSupport(contextHandler);

        // Spring Security
        enableSpringSecurity(contextHandler, context);

        /*
        // TODO: Does not seem to have any effect
        // Set reference to actual Spring ApplicationContext
        ServletContext servletContext = contextHandler.getServletContext();
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, context);
        */

        // Set resource base folder
        contextHandler.setBaseResource(getResourceBase());

        // Add DispatcherServlet to context
        final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder("default", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servletHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
        contextHandler.setContextPath("/oauth");
        contextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/");

        // Add context to server
        server.setHandler(contextHandler);
    }

    private Resource getResourceBase() {
        File file = new File("src/website/application.war");
        //servletHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", getWebRootResourceUri().toASCIIString());
        final Resource base = Resource.newResource(file);
        return base;
    }

    /**
     * Apply existing securityFilterChain to context
     *
     * @param contextHandler
     * @param context
     */
    private void enableSpringSecurity(ServletContextHandler contextHandler, WebApplicationContext context) {

        FilterChainProxy filter = (FilterChainProxy) context.getBean("springSecurityFilterChain");
        FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder(filter);
        contextHandler.addFilter(filterHolder, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

        server.setSessionIdManager(new HashSessionIdManager());

        HashSessionManager manager = new HashSessionManager();
        SessionHandler sessions = new SessionHandler(manager);
        contextHandler.setHandler(sessions);
    }

    /**
     * Setup JSP Support for ServletContextHandlers.
     * <p>
     * NOTE: This is not required or appropriate if using a WebAppContext.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param servletContextHandler the ServletContextHandler to configure
     * @throws IOException if unable to configure
     */
    private void enableEmbeddedJspSupport(ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler) throws IOException {
        // Establish Scratch directory for the servlet context (used by JSP compilation)
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File scratchDir = new File(tempDir.toString(), "embedded-jetty-jsp");

        if (!scratchDir.exists()) {
            if (!scratchDir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create scratch directory: " + scratchDir);
            }
        }
        servletContextHandler.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", scratchDir);

        // Set Classloader of Context to be sane (needed for JSTL)
        // JSP requires a non-System classloader, this simply wraps the
        // embedded System classloader in a way that makes it suitable
        // for JSP to use
        ClassLoader jspClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        servletContextHandler.setClassLoader(jspClassLoader);

        // Manually call JettyJasperInitializer on context startup
        servletContextHandler.addBean(new JspStarter(servletContextHandler));

        // Create / Register JSP Servlet (must be named "jsp" per spec)
        ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder("jsp", JettyJspServlet.class);
        holderJsp.setInitOrder(0);
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("logVerbosityLevel", "DEBUG");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("fork", "false");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerTargetVM", "1.8");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerSourceVM", "1.8");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("keepgenerated", "true");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(holderJsp, "*.jsp");
    }

    /**
     * JspStarter for embedded ServletContextHandlers
     *
     * This is added as a bean that is a jetty LifeCycle on the ServletContextHandler. This bean's doStart method will
     * be called as the ServletContextHandler starts, and will call the ServletContainerInitializer for the jsp engine.
     *
     */
    public static class JspStarter extends AbstractLifeCycle
            implements ServletContextHandler.ServletContainerInitializerCaller {
        JettyJasperInitializer sci;
        ServletContextHandler context;

        public JspStarter(ServletContextHandler context) {
            this.sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
            this.context = context;
            this.context.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner", new StandardJarScanner());
        }

        @Override
        protected void doStart() throws Exception {
            ClassLoader old = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(context.getClassLoader());
            try {
                sci.onStartup(null, context.getServletContext());
                super.doStart();
            } finally {
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(old);
            }
        }
    }

    private URI getWebRootResourceUri() throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        String WEBROOT_INDEX = "/application.war/";

        URL indexUri = this.getClass().getResource(WEBROOT_INDEX);

        if (indexUri == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find resource " + WEBROOT_INDEX);
        }

        File file = new File("src/website/application.war");
        System.out.println(indexUri.toURI());
        System.out.println(file.toURI());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

        return file.toURI();
    }
}
```

The WebApplicationContext for the test case is simply provided somewhat like this:

```
...
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ATestClass {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    ...
    @Before
    public void setupTest() throws Exception {
        new JettyServerFactory().start(context);
        ...
    }
    ...
...
```

Location of the Resource Base:
[Resource placement in the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkphS.png)

All static resources like css, js and images are in **themes**

#### What does work:

- Controllers are hit on requests
- Spring Security is active
- JSPs are found and rendered (thanks to https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp)

#### What does not work:

- All other static resources are missing (css, js, images, etc.). Basically everything from **themes**

#### So, what are my questions:

1. How can I make the missing static resources available?
2. Is there a completely different/better approach to achieve my ultimate goal? The way, to what I have now, was quite rocky and I'm not sure the missing static content is the last of my problems.

I'm happy to provide additional information/code. But, since this is an actual product, I have some limits on that.

### Edits:

1. [Picture of the resource structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJoeX.png)
   Mind that application.war is just a folder, not actually a war
2. Resource Config

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppWebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        boolean developmentMode = configuration.getBooleanFromNewconfig(false, "oauth2.developmentMode");
        if (USE_VERSIONED_RESOURCES) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/themes/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/themes/")
                    .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                    .resourceChain(developmentMode ? false : true)
                    .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                    .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
        } else {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/themes/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/themes/")
                    .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Which case is used for the ResourceHandler doesn't matter. Neither works.

Comment: Where are the "themes" files?  (Hopefully in the `src/website/application.war`) being referenced.

Comment: You might want to describe in your question how you have your mvc resources configured too. - See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482687/775715

Comment: I have edit my question. Hope this is what you are interested in.
Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much more information rich question.  Sadly, I cannot help with the spring side, as my expertise is in Jetty.  But hopefully someone on spring side can help. (i'll tweak the tags to be in more popular tags)